# Istanbul coverage nested directories in HTML report

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, code-coverage, istanbul, test-coverage

The unit test coverage report from [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) in HTML format displays every single folder of the project in the `index.html`.

It actually flattens the directory structure. Is there an option to render the html report with nested folders?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the coverage reporter attribute with 'lcov', it should be possible to view using a tool. It does give a folder structure.
eg: https://lcov-viewer.netlify.app/report

Answer (score 0):

Copying [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73495074/3624264) from a potential [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44995252/3624264):

> Maybe try the `--reporter=html-spa` option.
>
> See [available options](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/blob/master/packages/istanbul-reports/lib/html-spa/index.js#L41-L62).
>
> [image: Example output (redacted)]

Answer (score -3):

With Istanbul's new CLI, [**nyc**](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc), it is possible to create a `.nycrc` configuration file and specify using an array of globs, **what files you want to include** in your coverage report:

```
{
    ...
    "include": [
        "**/dist/myfile*.js",
        "**/test/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Also it is possible to specify **what files should be excluded** too:

```
{
    ...
    "exclude": [
        "**/dist/myfile*.js",
        "**/test/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    ...
}
```

[**More about this on GitHub**](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#excluding-files).