# Grouping istanbul code coverage report by folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, istanbul, nyc

I'm running a code coverage report for NodeJs using istanbul and the nyc command.

I'm using mocha for my unit tests

I get a report for each file just as expected, but what I'd like to see is a report that has a single directory summary. Let me explain in a bit more detail what I'm getting verses what I'd like to see

All my source files are in a single folder and I'd like to see a summary of that one folder instead of a full list of every file in that folder

Here is what my folder structure looks like

```
// This is the folder where all the sources are at 
src
    // This is the folder where coverage is output
    coverage
        NodeJs
            index.html
    file1.js
    file2.js
    file3.js
    // This is the folder where all tests are at
    tests
        test_file1.js
        test_file2.js
        test_file3.js
```

My `.babelrc` file looks like this

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "istanbul",
            {"exclude": ["**/tests/*.js"]}
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm using the following command to run my tests with coverage

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/nyc --reporter=html \
    --report-dir=./src/coverage/NodeJs \
    ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha \
    --require babel-core/register \
    --ui bdd src/tests/test*.js
```

All my tests run fine, they pass, and the report gets output to the `src/coverage/NodeJs/index.html` file as expected. In a browser, that report looks something like this:

[image: Coverage report for all files]

What I'd like to see is something like this where I can see a single full summary of the entire folder and then click on the folder to burrow down into it if necessary like this:

[image: Coverage report for single folder]

Now, I can kinda get that effect if I have more than 1 folder that's covered. For example... If I get rid of the `exclude` in my `.babelrc` file, then there are 2 directories that are being covered (`src` and `src/tests`) and I get a summary of each like so

[image: Coverage report with two folders]

But the problem with this is that I don't want my tests being covered... as you can see, it messes up the numbers. I just want a single folder being covered and would like to see a single folder summary in the HTML output file.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? (And if I didn't give enough information, please let me know)

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Never did resolve this issue. I just accepted that it isn't possible. Well... I'm sure it's possible, I'd just have to write my own reporter that takes the raw __coverage__ data and outputs a report the way I want it to look. I answered a question about instrumentation and how coverage data gets generated. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075076/what-is-instrumentation-in-nyc-istanbul/59626976#59626976)

Comment: I actually couldn't believe that nobody thought of adding an option to show the coverage data grouped by files - after all, there is a reason I chose to structure my project the way I did.

Comment: @Benni Agreed. There really should be an option

Comment: Did you ever consider opening a PR with https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs to add this option, specifically `istanbul-reports`?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you redirect the output to the same folder, i.e. unify the folder holding all results?

[This](https://nodejs.dev/learn/working-with-folders-in-nodejs) might help!

Or maybe instead of Instabul alone, try **adding** NYC too as:

My .babelrc file looks like this

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "istanbul","NYC",
            {"exclude": ["**/tests/*.js"]}
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: @UnknownReality - Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately, this question is over 4 years old and I no longer use istanbul code coverage so I can't test to see if this solves the issue... If someone out there would like to try and confirm that this answer works, I'll mark it as solved. Otherwise, I'll set everything up again and see if it works myself once I get some spare time.

Comment: @RayPerea, you are most welcomed man, I myself am not a fan of Node.js but some logical analysis and a bit of google search never fail. Good luck with your work man

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the `--reporter=html-spa` option.

See [available options](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/blob/master/packages/istanbul-reports/lib/html-spa/index.js#L41-L62).

[image: Example output (redacted)]

Comment: Seems not working now.