# How do I generate code coverage for some Node.JS code without tests?

Tags: node.js, code-coverage, nyc

I have a `build/` folder that gets autogenerated by a babel process in a `package.json`.  It has several .js files, including in sub-folders.  In the root is a file, `main.js`, which is something of a demo / testbed for the project, that instantiates various ES6 classes and tries out various functions.  It currently runs without crashing.

Call it a poor man's end-2-end test.  I'm trying to move quickly with what could be throw away code.

I don't have any formal tests.  I don't want to write any formal tests for this codebase.  But I am interested in knowing how much of the code in `build/` is being touched currently by my demo, `main.js`.

1. How can I generate a code coverage report for this scenario, using `nyc`?
2. If that's not actually easy (all tutorials I see seem to involve instrumenting pre-existing unit tests from a mainstream testing framework), what nyc alternative would make this easy?

I tried

```
npm install nyc --save-dev
npx nyc node build/main.js
```

but it claimed 0 lines/files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to [What is instrumentation in nyc istanbul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075076/what-is-instrumentation-in-nyc-istanbul), it was actually simple.  From the root, where my package.json and build/ folder were:

```
npx nyc instrument build coverage
npx nyc --reporter=text --report-dir=./nyc_output node build/main.js
```

all necessary folders (coverage, nyc_output) were auto-created (though it made `.nyc_output/` for some reason)